# Styling column entries in an email generated by SQL+HTML script

Tags: html, css, sql, sql-server

I am using SQL+HTML script to send an email containing columns of a table `mytable`. Currently, I have all the column titles aligned centrally and each column entries aligned to the right using `[th]` and `[td]` repsectively. How can I make entries in `Vendor` column left aligned while keeping everything else the same? 
This issue has been bugging me for a long time. I would appreciate a helping hand.

```
if(@@ROWCOUNT>0)
        begin
            --drop table #email
            DECLARE @Body2 varchar(max)
            declare @TableHead2 varchar(max)
            declare @TableTail varchar(max)
            Set @TableTail = '</table></body></html>';

  Set @TableHead2 = '<html><head>' +
            '<hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;">'+
            '<H5 style="color: #000000; font-family:Arial">2: VENDOR LEVEL TOP 5 OUTL $ <font color="blue">INCREMENTS -</font></H5>' +
            '<style>' +

            'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:10pt;color:Black;text-align:right;font-family:Arial;} ' +
            'th {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:10pt;color:Black;text-align:center;font-family:Arial;} ' +
            '</style>' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=auto>' +
            '<tr bgcolor=#007336>'+
            '<th><b><font color="white">Vendor_Name</font></b></th>' +
            '<th><b><font color="white">OUTL$ New</font></b></th>' +
            '<th><b><font color="white">OUTL$ Old</font></b></th>' +
            '<th><b><font color="white">OUTL$ Diff</font></b></th>' + 
            '<th><b><font color="white">Analyst_Name</font></b></th></tr>';

            --Select information for the Report-- 
            Select @Body2= (select 
                        Vendor_Name As [TD]
                        ,OUTL_New_$ As [TD]
                        ,OUTL_Old_$ As [TD]
                        ,OUTL_Diff_$ As [TD]
                        ,Analyst_Name As [TD]

            from #mytable
            For XML raw('tr'), Elements)

            Set @Body = @TableHead2 + @Body2 + @TableTail

            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @recipients='abc@abc.com',
            @subject = My analysis',
            @body = @Body,
            @body_format = 'HTML'; 
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Before font-family:Arial; I would insert 'align;left;' Then add a closing H5 tag after your $ sign, then a new H5 tag.
 What I see here is 2 styling attributes assigned across displayed text. Use the extra close and open tag to make separate left and right H5 displays.
 The right H5 may also need a float:right command or even add a margin-right:1px; (insert the correct number of pixels to position it right where you want it).
 I work with tables a lot and they are fussy about details, especially when the headers need to align with the columns.
 Table cells do NOT inherit css. Each td and th needs its own style commands. I use style 'classes' (sometimes an 'h5' tag) for general purpose position and color, font, font-size, etc, but I still often have to add a style tag to the headers to fine-trim their position using the align, float and margin attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<colgroup>` tag.

Example:

```html
 <table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2" style="background-color:red">
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would define 3 columns so the 'td' tags are aligned with their own assigned space, then modify the 'col span' of the leftmost 'th' tag to span the width desired (th colspan="2"). This keeps the table under rigid control.

Comment: @Sparky256: It's just an example.

Comment: Understood. A simple table can be pages of code because the cells do not inherit class styling.